# Running an ASP.Net core app which is inside another ASP.Net core app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis-7.5

i have created sample MVC Core app from the template and inside this app i have created a folder called module and inside this folder i have put the published files from another MVC core app, now is their a way that i can run that module folder. The first level application works as expected but second level app does not work. The first level application path is 'http://localhost/MyApp/' and the second level application path is 'http://localhost/MyApp/Module' i am using IIS 7.5 with dotnet core bundle installed.

Comment: Do you want this to work on IIS Express/Visual Studio or deployed in IIS?

Comment: For testing i'm using IIS but in the future i will host this on Linux with Nginx.

Comment: You will need to create 2 applications on IIS: one for the root and another for /Module

Comment: I know but i want to avoid this because i want the users to upload the web app from the web dashboard.

Comment: You cannot avoid that. You have two applications you need two applications on IIS. You won't have any problem besides having to configure CORS

Comment: Can i achieve this without using IIS and by using kestrel or any web server.

Comment: I don't think so, you'd likely have to do the same with Nginx. You are probably better off with one single application

Comment: Is there no way that IIS can convert the folder to application without me manually do it. I want this process to be automated.

Comment: No. There is not. If you look at the Web.config, you'll see that the ASP.NET Core app is actually be run as a module, and importantly, it only runs the main app. When IIS serves the site, it reads the Web.config, loads the ASP.NET Core app (the main one only) into your app pool and then moves on. In order for it to do the same for your sub app, it would also have to have a site record for that. Period. End of story. Further, this will be the case with *any* web server.

Comment: At the end of the day, an ASP.NET Core app is still a compiled application. It's not a scripting language like PHP. That means it has a single entry point and something must "activate" that.